# JS Files/Libraries Return HTTP 500 on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, safari, mobile-safari

I am running my web application on PC devices without any problems (no 404 or 500), however when I run it on iOS (and log it using Safari's Web Inspector) I am seeing that I am getting a couple of HTTP 500 for some JS/Jquery libraries:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) (jquery.min.map, line 0)
```

The functionality from some of the files are still available, whereas some are not running. Please note that the location I am getting the 500 for libraries is:

```
http://myserverip/path/to/currentpage/jquery.min.map
```

which is not where I store my files. I reference them like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Maybe you're not actually using the same URL? Otherwise, look at the server to see why it's returning different results for the same request. Maybe it considers user agent or other headers

Comment: There is not a single this issue related error log in the server I am afraid. I am referencing these files like "/static/path/to/file.js"

Comment: If your server returns an HTTP 5xx status then it's a server side error. If there are no server logs of this then your server logging is broken.

Answer (score 0):

error 500 is a server error. please check your web service again as this is not a problem from your client.

errors 5XX are server related.

please check if the parameters you send to the server is well formed and without error.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your answer. However, in the comments above I posted that I am not getting any server logs related to this issue. And I wonder if the requests and parameters would change from a laptop safari to mobile safari.

Comment: could you please and a little bit of server code related to the page you are trying to access. it is possible to not have server logs because of different factors, such as exception handling, logging filter and etc. this    " Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500"    looks like a reference error. maybe you are using information form the browser to load some resources. possible responsive layout using different resources for mobile  and another for desktop browsers?